# How to avoid very long paths and use absolute paths within a Create React App project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, absolute-path

Is there a `babel` plugin to avoid long import path in CRA?
I've searching a lot on the web but I can't find the best way to achieve this.

Actual:

```
import MyComponent from '../../../../components/MyComponent'
```

Expected

```
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your main root, [create file `jsconfig.json`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports):

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src"
   },
   "include": ["src"]
}
```

Where `src` is the folder where you store your project files, sometimes it may be `/app` or `/src`.

Then you will be able to import your components with an absolute path:

```
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent';
```

Comment: I added a link to the documentation in your answer, feel free to improve/change my edit ;)

Comment: @kinduser Thank you. I've missing the `absolute path` search term :) This method don't need to configure babel or anymore; Awesome.